# Python linked list: Connect head with linked list node

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

I am trying to convert a number to a linked list (e.g. 617 to 7->1->6)

here is my code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    # @param l1: the first list
    # @param l2: the second list
    # @return: the sum list of l1 and l2 
        def addLists(self, l1, l2):
            # write your code here
            num_1 = num_2 = 0
            counter = 1

            # convert each linked list to an integer
            while l1 != None:
                num_1 += l1.val * counter
                l1 = l1.next
                counter *= 10

            # reset counter
            counter = 1
            while l2 != None:
                num_2 += l2.val * counter
                l2 = l2.next
                counter *= 10

            # perform the addition        
            my_sum = num_1 + num_2

            # convert the sum back to a linked list
            # initialize head
            sum_head = ListNode(my_sum % 10)
            sum_node = sum_head
            my_sum //= 10

            while my_sum != 0:
                sum_node.next = ListNode(my_sum % 10)
                sum_node = sum_node.next
                my_sum //= 10

            # return the the linked list
            return sum_head
```

I coded this part and this piece of code works. I just don't understand why the "sum_head" is able to link to the second node "sum_node".

Here is an example in Python:

```
a = <Object>
b = a
```

b is just a reference to a, is this correct?

Say convert 617 to 7->1->6. Followed my code, the head is 7 and the rest of the linked list is 7->1->6. How can the head knows that the next node is 1?

Comment: No, `b` is not a reference to `a`. They are both names for the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two variables aren't "linked" in the linked-list sense. They are the same object. This might be clearer if it is substituted for an equivalent expression:

```
sum_head = ListNode(my_sum % 10)
sum_node = sum_head

# ==

sum_node = sum_head = ListNode(my_sum % 10)

# So: sum_node.next is sum_head.next
```

Why do we need two variables pointing to to the same object? Because in the following lines, we change what the sum_node points to. It will become the `.next` of the object it previously was. Since there is no way to go back, we need to keep a reference of the head to return it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
I do have a follow-up question:
Are there any differences between a = b = <int> and a = b = <object>?

Because I tried: a = b = 10, it doesn't work the way as it is a = b = ListNode(...)

Comment: @Terence `a = b = 10` works the same, but *integers are immutable*. So, when you later do `b += 1`, a new integer object for `11` is created and assigns it to `b`. This explains why `a` doesn't update, because it still reference the original integer object with the value of `10`. In short, `a = b = x` assigns `x` to both `a` and `b`, but there is nothing intrinsically relating `a` and `b` other than referencing the same object.  In Python, the most common immutable types are `int`, `str`, `tuple`, and `set`.

Comment: Thank you @JaredGoguen you are very helpful!